# Jquery history plugin ends in loop in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi i have my "proof of concept project" where i want to have data driven by ajax.

I have decided to use jquery history to record and allow users to use button back.

when i load my page and select link everything is working well untill i try to access the page from the url or do F5. In internet explorer, safari, chrome the plug in works well.
If i load the page in FireFox the page ends in loop trying to load the page.

My relevant javascript code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {
          // init history and set function that will handle history loading.
          $.history.init(loadContent, { unescape: true });

          // process history link
          $("span").not(".external").click(function () {
             var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
             var url = "/Home/Detail?id=" + id;
             $.history.load(url);
          });

          function loadContent(hash) {             
             if (hash != "") {
                $('#updateContainer').load(hash);
             }
          }
    </script>
```

Here is rar version of my project:

My project in VS 2010

http://www.mediafire.com/?5uocb90qcf9d0jp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OouKey,
I have found the problem on this.
I have done multiple errors.

1. Call history plug-in directly in some cases and others i called my method to load
2. If at all avoidable do not use jHistory and normal pages => its madness to make it working easily
3. Have partial views for the pages you use for this plug in

Comment: Hi cpoDesign, I am having exactly the same issue as you have documented. Can you elaborate on the solution you implemented to overcome this Firefox issue? Thanks.